# Изменение и/или создание нескольких сущностей одним HTTP запросом

Tags: moysklad-json-api, мойсклад-api

Через апи можно, например, создать модификацию. Но проблема в том, что (согласно примерам в документации) можно создавать одну сущность при одном HTTP запросе. А это очень долго и накладно. Вопрос в следующем - можно ли одним HTTP запросом создать/изменить несколько модификаций/товаров?

Answer (score -1):

Да, попробуйте через POST запрос https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

> curl -X POST \
>     https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product \
>     -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
>     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>     -d '[
>       {
>           "meta": {
>                   "href": "https://online-1.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/8fb97816-7e3c-11e9-2d11-ca8e0000b6eb",
>                   "metadataHref": "https://online-1.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata",
>                   "type": "product",
>                   "mediaType": "application/json",
>                   "uuidHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#good/edit?id=8fb964e7-7e3c-11e9-2d11-ca8e0000b6e9"
>               },
>               "name": "Товар с новым именем"
>       },
>       {
>           "meta": {
>                   "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/8fc853c6-7e3c-11e9-2d11-ca8e0000b6f5",
>                   "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata",
>                   "type": "product",
>                   "mediaType": "application/json",
>                   "uuidHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#good/edit?id=8fc83a44-7e3c-11e9-2d11-ca8e0000b6f3"
>               },
>               "name": "Другой товар с новым именем"
>       }
>   ]'

Comment: Максимальное кол-во объектов в запросе?

Comment: Не более 100 объектов в одном запросе

Comment: Как быть с обновлением? Ведь при обновлении нужно указать в url UUID сущности. Невозможно массовое изменение?

Comment: Запрос через POST, приведенный по ссылке работает также и для обновления.